# Ollydbg 2.1 Allow for multiple saves or not make backups

Tags: ollydbg, patching

I have been looking all around for an answer to this, so I am hoping I find an answer here.

I am working in Ollydbg 2.1 and every time I patch an exe it makes a foo.bak (backup) which is ok. However, I must reload the program to make more patches and often I am making multiple patches in multiple stubs at a time. Olly wont allow me to patch multiple times unless I rename the file cause there is a .bak already there and it wont over write that. I keep all my own backups so I am wondering.

1 Is there a way to have olly not make backups?
2 Is there a way to have olly allow forover writing the .bak files or some way to have multiple saves in a session?

Please let me know .

Thanks!

Comment: ollydbg does not create backups for opcode/ assembly editing it keeps all the patch info in a special window called patch providing an actual problem with i load notepad change je to jne at address 401234 use edit copy to executable it asks me to save i save it using a new name  next time ollydbg does not allow me to save  thus  one can try to reprduce might provide a better answer

Comment: This seems to be a repeat of what i said above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a hack for now... I think it would be better to not allow for it to make backups... Which I can do but for now this will just allow the changes to take place and JMP over the error sequence.

The Origional

```
OFFSET 004BDBF7 :JNZ SHORT 004BDC1B
```

Change to:

```
JMP 004BDC1B
```

I almost feel bad for this cause there is has to be an option somewhere that I am not seeing. Not to mention the whole inception feeling of debugging a debugger running another process. 0.o...